# How to use % formatting in the below SQL query instead of f' string format?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, logging

How to use % formatting in the below query. I have schema and table name as parameter. The reason I want to use % formatting because I am unable to log the query in logging file.

```
import logging
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

query_random = f"""(select * from {SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME}
       where xyz =4
       and abc = 1
       fetch first 10000 rows only)as some_name"""

logging.info("Sql query: " + str(query_random))
#logging.info(f"Sql query : {query_random}")


df = spark.read.format("jd")\
                      .option("url", jd_url)\
                      .option("driver",jd_driver)\
                      .option("dbtable" ,query_random)\
                      .option("user", user)\
                      .option("password", password).load()

print(df)
```

Comment: you can't, it is only for parameters

Comment: @nbk Is there any way to get the above query in the log file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for string replacemrnt in the logger

```
SCHEMA = 'TEST'
TABLE_NAME = 'testa'
query_random = f"""(select * from {SCHEMA}.{TABLE_NAME}
       where xyz =4
       and abc = 1
       fetch first 10000 rows only)as some_name"""
logging.info(query_random)
logging.warning('%s run %s','me',query_random)
```

more about logging see [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)